# Can't run go tests from GoLand (Intellij Idea): compilation failed

Tags: go, testing, intellij-idea, goland

I've made simple application in go and trying to run tests with GUI tools of GoLand.

In myfile_test.go file near test func I press green button that should start test. But I get error message: "Compilation failed" and message in console:

```
# command-line-arguments [command-line-arguments.test]
./myfile_test.go:21:11: undefined: MyStruct
./myfile_test.go:22:12: undefined: MyFuncName
./myfile_test.go:33:12: undefined: AnotherStruct

Compilation finished with exit code 2
```

Other variants (Run test with Coverage/CPU Profile) don't work either. GoLand 2020.1 EAP. The same problem occurred in older versions of GoLand.

But test from console starts normally:

```
go test -v

=== RUN   TestMyStruct_MyMethod
--- PASS: TestMyStruct_MyMethod (0.00s)
PASS
ok      _/home/username/projects/my_project_name     0.002s
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer from @porfirion worked for me.

Basically, you need to tick "Enable Go Modules integration" in GoLand under "Preferences" -> "Go" -> "Go Modules"

Goland will then reindex your project and this can take a long time if you have a large project with many modules. Mine took 30 mins. You can check the reindexing progress status at the bottom of the IDE.

The test run will work after the reindexing.

Comment: You also need to run `go mod init` to create a go.mod file as in @porfirion's answer.  I also found that it did not work until I closed the project and reopened.

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem with initializing new go module and enabling Go Modules Integration:

1) Run in Terminal `go mod init my_module_name`

2) Click "File -> Settings" or press Ctrl+Alt+S

3) Check "Enable Go Modules Integration" and Apply button [image: project settings window]

Now all test functionality in GoLand works well (including tests with coverage, etc.)

Comment: In my casee I moved my project from under the *go* directory (Linux) to elsewhere because I was having permission issues there. Then I could no longer Run or Debug the project.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you're pointing to a single file. All other files, even though they're in the package, aren't going to be imported. `go build` has the same behaviour, if you are targeting a single file to build and forget to include other files it uses in the command.

Change the test kind to "Directory" and files to `"/project-root-dir"`. This will then include all files in the directory during build and should look for all `_test.go` files to execute tests.

Comment: It works! Unfortunately every time I click on single test - IDEA creates new configuration and it is always has kind "File". Even if I change kind to "Directory" manually and click on method again - IDEA creates one more configuration with kind "File". Very disappointing(

Comment: I found this answer did not work. You can't control the "Test kind" option when you try to run/debug a specific test using the green arrow button. If you change the "test kind" setting in the "Run/Debug Configurations" then GoLand creates a new config with "test kind" = file when you debug a single specific test. I found the only way is to (1) place your project in GOPATH or (2) use modules (as explained in the other answers)